# C# // SendKeys.SendWait works only when process'es window is minimzed

Tags: c#, sendkeys

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;


namespace TextSendKeys
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("game");
            Process game1 = processes[0];


            IntPtr p = game1.MainWindowHandle;

            ShowWindow(p,1);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");



        }
    }
}
```

That program is suposed to send twice DOWN button in a game window. It only works, when my window is minimized (it's activating the window and doing it's job). If my window is activated (not minimized), nothin happens. How to solve that?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you do without a window? Try creating a console program if you don't really need a window.

Comment: while using through console application getting error like this "the name 'SendKeys' does not exist in the current context. ". how can i resolve this error. @Autodidact

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using the [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539.aspx) Win32 API call, instead of `ShowWindow`, to activate the game window. (Signature from [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/setforegroundwindow.html).)

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("game");
    Process game1 = processes[0];

    IntPtr p = game1.MainWindowHandle;

    SetForegroundWindow(p);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    SendKeys.SendWait("{DOWN}");
}
```