# c# -> How to send keys to a flash movie running in the browser?

Tags: c#, flash, send, key, sendkeys

I tried setting the browser as active windows and using SendKeys but it does not work. Is there an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the `SetForegroundWindow` Windows API call on the browser window? Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953524/1149773 for some sample code.